# textarea height does not increase to match table cell height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a textarea which fits into a table cell known as `.question`. Now the problem I am having is that if the table cell's height expands to an increased height, the textarea's height does not increase and thus leaves a gap between the top table cell border and the top of the textarea border and it also leaves a gap in between the textarea's bottom border and the table cell's bottom border.

If the table cell's height decreases enough, then it looks like that the textarea has filled the table cell's height.

But what my question is that no matter if the table cell's height has been altered, the textarea should fill the table cell's height always. My question is though that how can I alter the css, HTML and jquery below in order to do this?

css:

```
    .question { 
        max-width:0.1%;
        border:1px black solid;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        line-height: 0;
    }

    .question textarea {
        width:auto;
        resize:none;
        height:100%;
        font-size:100%;
        display: block; 
        overflow:auto;

    }
```

Jquery:

```
function setWidth() {
    var questionCellHeight = $("#qandatbl_onthefly tbody .question").height();
    $(".textAreaQuestion").css({
        "height": (questionCellHeight) + "px"
    });
}
```

HTML Table:

```
<table id="qandatbl" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="question">Question</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
<div id="qandatbl_onthefly_container">
<table id="qandatbl_onthefly" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>
<td class='question'>
<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

UPDATE:

Slight update of css where I changed `.question textarea` to `.textAreaQuestion` and removed the height attribute:

```
.textAreaQuestion{
    resize:none;
    font-size:100%;
    display: block; 
    overflow:auto;
}
```

I believe the jquery needs to be editted so that if the table cell increase, it will increase the hieight of the text area to the same height as the increase table cell. (opinion)

Comment: It looks like you have a few mistakes in your code. Your css references `questionTextArea` but your HTML class name is `textAreaQuestion`. But then you're also trying to stylize it above with `.question textarea`? And then you're also trying to set the width with JS as well?

Comment: @DigTheDoug Sorry questionTextArea should not be in the css above, that is for a different textarea class, I will remove it. Im assuming you want me to remove the height and width css elements from `.question textarea` and also change `.question textarea` to `textAreaQuestion`?

Comment: Well the problem with trying to find out where your error lies (not just for me, but when you are debugging as well) is that you have too much code that could be affecting it. Start by trimming it down to one class style on that element and see from there what you get. That goes for the Javascript as well, I would take it out until you think you absolutely will need it, because chances are you shouldn't need it to do this. I usually use Chrome's developer tools to live change the element's styles to see if I can isolate the problem or fix it on the fly before committing it to the stylesheet.

Comment: @DigTheDoug It is defintely the jquery I need to alter in order to solve this. The jquery does its best to increase the height of the textarea even though it doesn't do it if table cell increases from original size but it does manage to get textarea to fill original table cell height. Without the jquery, the textarea will not fill the table cell height at all even though in css I stated height:100%. I have included an update to show css change to `.textAreaQuestion` rather than `.question textarea` and remove the height attribute from the css but at moment it is still doing same thing.

Comment: @DigTheDoug I don't know if its possible but is there a way in jquery to state that if table cell increases, increase the height of the textarea up to same height as table cell? That might have to be way to solve it.

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2FW9/) of your code. Please reduce the code like @DigTheDoug said. Also update your question with the reduced code when you update the jsfiddle. I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok For me to show like a live version, I will have to add like a lot of code on because what happens in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LKB9e/12/ is that when you click on the "Add Question" button, it appends a table row and you can see that the textarea is full height in its table cell under "Question" column. But that table cell increases (can't really show you live example without showing loads more code), then the table cell height doesn't increase. You can see I have tried reducing the code already as much as possible in the fiddle and code provided in question

Comment: @MiniRagnarok let me get a live version you can see on the browser and then in my update, I will state how to use the application and there you can see the problem, give me 10 mins.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Here is a link to the application [link](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable4.php). Just use the app to see the output. When you open app, on top left hand side you see green plus img button, click on it then in search bar type in `single` then submit search. Add a row by clicking on `Add` button. when modal window closes, click on `Add Question` button, this will append a row underneath in a table. Now in appended row under `Option and Answer` column, select `Open Grid` and select button 26. You will see the table cells have slightly increase to be able to ...

Comment: ...show all the buttons, but in the `Question` column next to this column, the textarea containing the question has not increased. That is the problem.

Comment: Just set the height to 100% instead of calculating the height.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Height of 100% doesn't work, I trid this previously before I included the jquery function

Comment: Then refresh the jQuery after you select a new button.

Comment: Also, I changed the height to 100% in Chrome, then selected button 26 and it did expand.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok I will have to ask you how to refresh the jquery code after new button is selected. I will include the 100% height again. I will mark your answer once you provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is call the jQuery function again, try adding something like `$(".gridBtns").click(setWidth);` to whatever handles the Grid.

I'm afraid I don't know exactly what you need because there's either too much or too little information to go on. Try to narrow your problem down and put just the problem in a jsfiddle. When it was asked from you before, you did the opposite. You just kept adding code to replicate your problem.

On a side note, please stop using `tables` for layout, that's what `divs` are for.